# Java InputStream: copy to and calculate hash at the same time

Tags: java, java-io, java-nio

Here are my two code snippets:

```java
public class Uploader {

  private static final String SHA_256 = "SHA-256";

  public String getFileSHA2Checksum(InputStream fis) throws IOException {
    try {
      MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA_256);
      return getFileChecksum(md5Digest, fis);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      return "KO";
    }
  }

  public void transferTo(InputStream fis) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fis, file2);
  }
```

My code uses this class as:

Is it possible to `copyToFile` and `calculateChecksum` at the same time leveraging `InputStream` is open?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? Concurrency? Or do you just want to read the input stream once?

Comment: Some kind of chaining... I need to store inputstream to a file, but I'd like to calculate checksum since inputstream is being read... At the end, I need checksum and a file stored. Yes I want to read input stream once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`DigestInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/DigestInputStream.html) to calculate a hash while reading from a stream. That is, you wrap the original input stream with a `DigestInputStream` and read through the `DigestInputStream`. While reading the data, the message digest is automatically updated, and you can retrieve the digest after you read the entire stream.

Alternatively, you can use [`DigestOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/DigestOutputStream.html) to calculate a hash while writing to a stream.  In a similar vein, you wrap the destination output stream with a `DigestOutputStream` and write through the `DigestOutputStream`.

A quick and dirty example:

```java
var inputFile = Path.of("D:\\Development\\data\\testdata-csv\\customers-1000.csv");
var outputFile = Files.createTempFile("testoutput", ".dat");
var md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
try (var in = new DigestInputStream(Files.newInputStream(inputFile), md);
     var out = Files.newOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    in.transferTo(out);
} finally {
    Files.deleteIfExists(outputFile);
}

System.out.println(HexFormat.of().formatHex(md.digest()));
```

In terms of your existing code, you could do something like:

```java
public String transferAndHash(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    try {
        var md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        try (var digestIn = new DigestInputStream(in, md)) {
            transferTo(digestIn);
        }
        return HexFormat.of().formatHex(md.digest());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // all recent Java versions are required to support SHA-256
        throw new AssertionError("Expected SHA-256 to be supported", e);
    }
}
```

(NOTE: `HexFormat` was introduced in Java 17, if you're using an earlier version, you'll need an alternative.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `DigestInputStream` based on [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel)'s suggestion (which I liked):

```java
Path input = Paths.get("input_file");
Path output = Paths.get("output_file");
MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(input);
     DigestInputStream hashingStream = new DigestInputStream(is, algorithm)) {
    Files.copy(hashingStream, output);
}
byte[] digest = algorithm.digest();
// this line uses Apache Commons Codec to show the hex representation of the byte[]
String hash = Hex.encodeHexString(digest);
```

Comment: Java 17 comes with [`HexFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html), so you don't need to use external libraries anymore.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn’t use jdk 17 yet. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My input stream is an http form upload multipart stream... I need to delete file if user cancels upload... Any ideas?

Comment: @Jordi you can add a catch block to the try and use `Files.deleteIfExists` inside it.
`try (...) { ... } catch (Exception ex) { Files.deleteIfExists(output); }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the input stream once, you might manual read the bytes from the input string and write it to you file by yourself.

```
    private static final String SHA_256 = "SHA-256";
    private static final int BUFFER = 1024;

    public String writeToFile(InputStream fis, File outputFile) throws IOException {
        try (var fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); fis) {
            MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA_256);
            var buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
            var bytesRead = 0;
            while (true) {
                bytesRead = fis.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead < 0)
                    break;
                md5Digest.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                fout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            var checksume = md5Digest.digest();
            return Hex.encodeHexString(checksume);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return "KO";
        }
    }
```